# Enable viewBinding by default for new projects

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewbinding

To enable viewBinding I add this to gradle:

```
viewBinding
{
   enabled = true
}
```

Is there a way to have viewBinding enabled by default whenever I create a new project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to enable it by default as there is no setting or plugin available for this, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As it is for data binding as it is also for view binding. it happen in the grade by enabling it to true. Voilà!